# Consider the strings in A, B, ..., Z. How many 4 letter strings exist that contain exactly 2 Y's?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So, the way I thought about this is that there are basically five ways in which a string can be shaped. If we let the asterisk (*) represent any of the other letters (not Y, of course), all strings will take one of the following five forms:
Y Y * *
Y * Y *
Y * * Y
* * Y Y
* Y * Y

Since each asterisk can only be one of the twenty five letters that are not Y, is the correct answer $5 \cdot 25^2 = 3125$, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You forgot * Y Y *.

Comment: Thanks. So would that make it $6 \cdot 25^2=3750$?

Comment: Yes, as my answer suggests.

Comment: Oh, just saw your answer. Thanks again for responding.

Answer (score 1):

To choose two places to be $Y$ from four places, you have $\dbinom 4 2 = 6$ choices.

There are $25$ choices for both of the remaining places, which gives you in total $\dbinom 4 2 \left( 25 \right)^2 = 3750$ choies.